# result not showing get id in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

URL:

```
empdetail.php?id=1
```

I have two tables in my MySQL database. I want to merge two tables and I think I done it. There may be some problem in $`_GET['id']` or other code. When I click `empdetail.php?id=1`, the result is showing perfectly. When I click `empdetail.php?id=2` or `empdetail.php?id=3` and others, no result is showing. I don't know why its not showing any result.

```
   <?
    //////Displaying Data/////////////

       //connect to database

         mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
         mysql_select_db('cdcol');

    $id=$_GET['id']; // Collecting data from query string
    if(!is_numeric($id)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
        echo "Data Error"; 
        exit;
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick

    $query = "SELECT ospos_employees.person_id, ospos_people.first_name ".
     "FROM ospos_employees, ospos_people ".
        "WHERE ospos_employees.person_id = ospos_people.person_id='$id'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


    // Print out the contents of each row into a table 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['person_id']. " - ". $row['first_name'];
        echo "<br />";
    }




    ?>
```

Comment: learn PDO http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers. mysql_* stack is depreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT ospos_employees.person_id, ospos_people.first_name ".
     "FROM ospos_employees, ospos_people ".
        "WHERE ospos_employees.person_id = ospos_people.person_id AND ospos_people.person_id =".$id;
```

I have one question: Why your query select from 2 tables. What about

```
 $query = "SELECT ospos_people.person_id, ospos_people.first_name ".
         "FROM  ospos_people ".
            "WHERE  ospos_people.person_id =".$id;
```

Comment: Note: PHP evaluates variables in double quotes so concatenating the string is not the issue. Suggestion: Point out the change so poeple can understand the answer

Comment: Ok, I am new here. Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, your SQL statement is wrong. Converting to straight up SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ospos_employees.person_id, ospos_people.first_name
FROM
    ospos_employees, ospos_people
WHERE 
    ospos_employees.person_id = ospos_people.person_id= '$id'
```

You will see your `WHERE` statement is wrong. You need to fix it. Either:

```
ospos_employees.person_id = '$id'
```

or

```
ospos_people.person_id= '$id'
```

or (if intended):

```
ospos_employees.person_id = '$id' AND ospos_people.person_id= '$id'
                                  ^^^
```

Also note that (int) values in a SQL does not need the tics around it.

**NOTICE:** DO NOT use MySQL_* functions as they have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi_* or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is my full answer:

```
 <?
    //////Displaying Data/////////////

       //connect to database

         mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
         mysql_select_db('cdcol');

    $id=$_GET['id']; // Collecting data from query string
    if(!is_numeric($id)){ // Checking data it is a number or not
    echo "Data Error"; 
    exit;
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); //the main trick

    $query = "SELECT ospos_employees.person_id, ospos_people.first_name 
             FROM ospos_employees
             inner join ospos_people on(ospos_employees.person_id = ospos_people.person_id)
             where ospos_employees.person_id = $id";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


    // Print out the contents of each row into a table 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['person_id']. " - ". $row['first_name'];
        echo "<br />";
    }




    ?>
```

Basically your query was wrong, i hope this helps.

Saludos ;)